# ¿Qué tiene este código mal que la variable posición esta tomando el primer y segundo valor?

Tags: android

En el siguiente código se ejecuta la variable ***posición***, está tomando el valor **0** y de una vez cambia al valor **1**, no se detiene en el valor **0**, este código es de una app android para manejar *`tabbed activity`*.

Este es el código:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // RETORNANDO EL TAB ACTUAL
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            FragmentBusqueda fragmentBusqueda = new FragmentBusqueda();
            return fragmentBusqueda;
        case 1:
            FragmentTurnos fragmentTurnos = new FragmentTurnos();
            return fragmentTurnos;
        case 2:
            FragmentCitas fragmentCitas = new FragmentCitas();
            return fragmentCitas;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Aqui esta el codigo de mi FragmentPagerAdapter

```
   package android.support.v4.app;

   import android.os.Parcelable;
   import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;


public abstract class FragmentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private static final String TAG = "FragmentPagerAdapter";
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;
private Fragment mCurrentPrimaryItem = null;

public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    mFragmentManager = fm;
}

/**
 * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
 */
public abstract Fragment getItem(int position);

@Override
public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    if (container.getId() == View.NO_ID) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager with adapter " + this
                + " requires a view id");
    }
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    final long itemId = getItemId(position);

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + 
        fragment);
        mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = getItem(position);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
    }
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Detaching item #" + getItemId(position) + ": f=" 
    + object
            + " v=" + ((Fragment)object).getView());
    mCurTransaction.detach((Fragment)object);
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
{
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
            mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
            mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
        }
        mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
    }
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    if (mCurTransaction != null) {
        mCurTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
        mCurTransaction = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
}

/**
 * Return a unique identifier for the item at the given position.
 *
 * <p>The default implementation returns the given position.
 * Subclasses should override this method if the positions of items can 
   change.</p>
 *
 * @param position Position within this adapter
 * @return Unique identifier for the item at position
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
}
}
```

Comment: Deberías colocar el `break` en cada `case`. No se si es buena práctica dejarlo sin `break`...

Comment: falta break en cada case despues del return.

Comment: En este ejemplo `return` crea el mismo efecto que el `break`, ponerlo no haría ninguna diferencia.

Comment: Es como dice @Lixus el break me da error si lo pongo.

Comment: @AngelGrullon es valido como lo tienes ya que asegura retornar un Fragment (o null) en todas las opciones.

Comment: Si @Jorgesys pero cuando ejecuto la app, esta entrando al case 0 y al case 1 de una vez, ese es el problema, no se que tiene mal o que me falta por poner.